# password protect QstandardItem pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QstandardItem that holds a password, I want to mask the value of this QstandardItem to password or a bunch of `******` even when you are editing the column.

```
username = QStandardItem("%s" % ("username"))
password = QStandardItem("%s" % ("password"))

self.tbViewModel.appendRow([username, password])
```

I want the user to be able to copy the actual password when they select the password column and CTRL+C.

Is there a way to password protect QStandardItem value?

Comment: You could override it's `paintEvent` method - see here for a tutorial: https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/painting/

Comment: @Programmer It is not necessary to use paintEvent as it can break the GUI styling, it is enough to change the text to be rendered.

Comment: @eyllanesc okay … that's what I'd have done, but your solution indeed looks better ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a role to indicate that it is a password and a delegate that uses that information to modify what is in the QLineEdit:

```
PasswordRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
```

```
password_item = QStandardItem("password")
password_item.setData(True, PasswordRole)
```

```
class PasswordDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.data(PasswordRole):
            style = option.widget.style() or QApplication.style()
            hint = style.styleHint(QStyle.SH_LineEdit_PasswordCharacter)
            option.text = chr(hint) * len(option.text)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if index.data(PasswordRole) and isinstance(editor, QLineEdit):
            editor.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        return editor
```

```
password_delegate = PasswordDelegate(your_view)
your_view.setItemDelegate(password_delegate)
```